# Finding polynomial without constant term that commutes with $f(x)=x^3+3x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, ring-theory

Consider the polynomial $f(x)=x^3+3x$ over $\mathbb{Z}$.

I am trying to find a polynomial $g(x)$  $(\neq f^{\circ n})$ of any degree (or series) without constant term which commutes with $f$ (or any iteration $f^{\circ n}, ~n \geq 1)$ under composition.

Trivially, any $g(x)=x$, is another polynomial (or series) commutes with $f(x)$.

By hand it seems to be laborious.

Suppose I start with an investigation if there are degree $2$ polynomial $g(x)=ax+bx^2$ such that $f \circ g=g\circ f$. Then
\begin{align}
&f(g(x))=f(ax+bx^2)=3(ax+bx^2)+(ax+bx^2)^3=3ax+3bx^2+a^3x^3+3a^2bx^4+3ab^2x^5+b^3x^6, \\
&g(f(x))=g(x^3+3x)=a(x^3+3x)+b(x^3+3x)^2=3ax+ax^3+bx^6+6bx^4+9bx^2
\end{align}

Comparing both equations, we get $b=0$ and $a=a^3 \Rightarrow a=\pm 1$. In this case $g(x)=\pm 1$, the trivial one.

Suppose I start with an investigation if there are degree $3$ polynomial $g(x)=ax+bx^2+cx^3$ such that $f \circ g=g\circ f$. Then
\begin{align}
&f(g(x))=f(ax+bx^2+cx^3)=3(ax+bx^2+cx^3)+(ax+bx^2+cx^3)^3=3ax+3bx^2+3cx^3+c^3x^9+3bc^2x^8 \hspace{3cm}+(3ac^2+3b^2c)x^7+(6abc + b^3)x^6 + (3a^2c + 3ab^2)x^5 + 3a^2bx^4 + a^3x^3, \\
&g(f(x))=g(x^3+3x)=a(x^3+3x)+b(x^3+3x)^2+c(x^3+3x)^3=3ax+ax^3+2bx^6+6bx^4+9bx^2+cx^9+9cx^7+27cx^5+27cx^3
\end{align}
Comparing both sides we get $b=0$ and the following equations:
\begin{align}
a^3-a=24c, \\
a^2c=9c, \\
3ac^2=9c,\\
c^3=c.
\end{align}
Solving these, we see $c^3=c$ and $3ac^2=a^2c$. These two gives us $c=0$ or $c=\pm 1$. If $c \neq 0$, then $a=\pm 3$. Thus $g(x)=\pm (3x+ x^3)$, which is equivalent to $f(x)$ upto signs.

Suppose I start with an investigation if there are degree $4$ polynomial $g(x)=ax+bx^2+cx^3+dx^4$ such that $f \circ g=g\circ f$. Then it becomes laborious.

Is there any way to find non-trivial $g$ with the help of PARI/GP or SAGE ?

**Edit 1:** According to the hints given by @achille hui, I have found that $g(x)=-5x-5x^3-x^5$  commutes with $x^3+3x$. However, I am looking for an polynomial whose first degree coefficient is $3$ or multiple of $3$. I would appreciate one such example.

**Edit 2:**  But I need to find the polynomial with degree one coefficient, a multiple of $3$ and it is certainly possible as $f$ commutes with its iteration and each iteration has the degree one coefficient , a multiple of 3

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132539/discussion-on-question-by-learner-finding-polynomial-without-constant-term-that).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have $$f(x):=x^3+3x$$ and you already found $$h(x)=x^5+5x^3+5x$$ with $$h(f(x))=f(h(x))$$
but the coefficient of $x$ of $h$ is not divisible by $3$. But $$g(x)=h(f(f(x)))$$
has this property because

$$g(x)=h(f(f(x)))=f(h(f(x))=(h(f(x))^3+3(h(f(x))$$
and the lowest non vanishing  power of $(h(f(x))^3$ is $x^3$ and all coefficients of $x$ in $3(h(f(x))$ are divisible by $3$.

And
$$g(f(x))=h(f(f(f(x)))=f(h(f(f(x)))=f(g(x))$$

(I missed that g(x):=h(f(x)) already has the required property- It is equal to the degree 15 polynomial I calculated in the second part of this post)

The polynomial $g(x)$ is

$${{x}^{45}}+45 {{x}^{43}}+945 {{x}^{41}}+12300 {{x}^{39}}
\\+111150 {{x}^{37}}+740259 {{x}^{35}}+3764565 {{x}^{33}}+14945040 {{x}^{31}}\\
+46955700 {{x}^{29}}+117679100 {{x}^{27}}+236030652 {{x}^{25}}+378658800 {{x}^{23}}\\
+483841800 {{x}^{21}}+488494125 {{x}^{19}}+384942375 {{x}^{17}}+232676280 {{x}^{15}}\\
+105306075 {{x}^{13}}+34512075 {{x}^{11}}+7811375 {{x}^{9}}+1138500 {{x}^{7}}\\
+95634 {{x}^{5}}+3795 {{x}^{3}}+45 x$$
which can be factored to

$$x\, \left( {{x}^{2}}+3\right) \, \left( {{x}^{4}}+5 {{x}^{2}}+5\right) \, \left( {{x}^{6}}+6 {{x}^{4}}+9 {{x}^{2}}+3\right) \,\\
 \left( {{x}^{8}}+7 {{x}^{6}}+14 {{x}^{4}}+8 {{x}^{2}}+1\right) \, \\
\left( {{x}^{24}}+24 {{x}^{22}}+252 {{x}^{20}}+1519 {{x}^{18}}\\
+5796 {{x}^{16}}+14553 {{x}^{14}}+24206 {{x}^{12}}+26169 {{x}^{10}}\\
+17523 {{x}^{8}}+6623 {{x}^{6}}+1182 {{x}^{4}}+72 {{x}^{2}}+1\right) $$

Here is a smaller one

${{x}^{15}}+15 {{x}^{13}}+90 {{x}^{11}}+275 {{x}^{9}}+450 {{x}^{7}}+378 {{x}^{5}}+140 {{x}^{3}}+15 x$

I calculated some polynomials with [Maxima](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/). The following commute with $f$ and are the only one with nonnegative leading coefficient and a highest power less or equal $15$:

$$0$$
$$x$$
$$x^3+3x$$
$$x^5+5x^3+5x$$
$$x^7+7x^5+14x^3+7x$$
$${{x}^{9}}+9 {{x}^{7}}+27 {{x}^{5}}+30 {{x}^{3}}+9 x$$
$${{x}^{11}}+11 {{x}^{9}}+44 {{x}^{7}}+77 {{x}^{5}}+55 {{x}^{3}}+11 x$$
$${{x}^{13}}+13 {{x}^{11}}+65 {{x}^{9}}+156 {{x}^{7}}+182 {{x}^{5}}+91 {{x}^{3}}+13 x$$
$${{x}^{15}}+15 {{x}^{13}}+90 {{x}^{11}}+275 {{x}^{9}}+450 {{x}^{7}}+378 {{x}^{5}}+140 {{x}^{3}}+15 x$$

Note that

$${{x}^{9}}+9 {{x}^{7}}+27 {{x}^{5}}+30 {{x}^{3}}+9 x=f(f(x))$$
and
$${{x}^{15}}+15 {{x}^{13}}+90 {{x}^{11}}+275 {{x}^{9}}+450 {{x}^{7}}+378 {{x}^{5}}+140 {{x}^{3}}+15 x = h(f(x))$$
where $$h(x)=x^5+5x^3+5$$

If we call these polynomials (excluding 0) $h_1,h_3,h_5,\ldots, h_{15}$, so the index $i$ of $h_i$ is the degree of the polynomials, the following holds:

$$h_i(x)=(x^2+2)h_{i-1}(x)-h_{i-2}(x)$$

---

Here is an [online version of Maxima](http://maxima.cesga.es/). This is how I calculated the coefficients of $h_9$ by comparing the coefficients of $(f(g(x))$ and $g(f(x))$ `N:9` is the degree of the polynomial `g(x)`. The statement starting with `empty` checks if all coefficients of the difference $(f(g(x))-g(f(x))$ become $0$. If the result of this statement is false, the solution is invalid. This happens if we choose $N$ and even number.

```
f(x):=x^3+3*x;
N:9;
g(x):=x^N+sum(a[i]*x^(i-1),i,1,N);
d:f(g(x))-g(f(x)),expand$
coeff_list:makelist(coeff(d,x,i),i,3*N,0,-1)$
eqn_list:makelist(coeff_list[i],i,2,N+1)$
var_list:makelist(a[i],i,1,N)$
solutions:solve(eqn_list,var_list);
emptyp(sublist(coeff_list,lambda([t], is(t#0)))),solutions;
expression:g(x);
expression,solutions;
```

Here is [the same algorithm implemented as SmPy scirpt](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/272302/12462).

---

These polynomials are related to [Chebyshev Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials)  as some commenters pointed out.
In the comments alex.jordan linked to [A082985](https://oeis.org/A082985)  and Lubin mentions the comments of achillehui of the OPs questions, which contains references to a paper  on this topic by [F.J.Ritt, Permutable Rational Functions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/272302/12462).

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A082985.

Comment: Ahh! It is excellent. I already found out the f(f(x)) one. But you found lots. I really appreciate your help

Comment: These are Čebyšev polynomials of some sort. It’s Ritt’s Theorem, referenced by @achillehui.

Comment: @mirace173, just one comment. You have created $g(x)=9x+30x^3+27x^5+9x^7+{{x}^{9}}$. Let $h(x)=x^m, \ m \geq 2$. Can you help me to create another polynomial $q(x)$ such that $(g(x))^m=q(x^m)$. For $m=1$, it is trivial taking $g(x)=q(x)$. But for $m \geq 2$, I don't know

Comment: @learner I think this should be a new question an I think I am not able to help you.

Comment: @miracle173, thanks a lot. It was very helpful answer. The `code` was beautiful. I just checked by running

Comment: @miracle173, you mean $h_9$ not $H_9$

Comment: @miracle173, I tried to find out a polynomial which commutes with $x^9+18x^8+135x^7+546x^6+1287x^5+1782x^4+1386x^3+540x^2+81x$ using your Maxima code, but not giving. Can you please look into it ? Thanks

Comment: @learner What is the purpose of all these polynomials? Why do you need them?

Comment: @miracle173, I am constructing a commuting family of polynomials and do some theoretical study that is in my mind. Your answer was very helpful and I can start my study once I know a polynomial $h(x)$ that commutes with $x (x+3)^2 \left(x (x+3)^2+3\right)^2$. I tried with your Maxima code but failed. Can you help me just once more ? Thanks

Comment: @learner I seems that the number of terms becomes too large to be handled by the program, In you case your  polynomial is f(f(x)), where f(x)=x^3+6*x^2+9*x, so you can try to find a g, such that g(f(x))=f(g(x)) and this g is commutative with your polynomial too, The Maxima command `polydecomp(x*(x+3)^2*(x*(x+3)^2+3)^2,x)` will calculate f.

Comment: @miracle173, Thanks. I used your trick to ask Maxima to give a polynomial which commute with $x^3+6x^2+9x$  and I got $g$ and this $g$ commutes with $f(f(x))$, the polynomial in my question. Thanks a lot. But can you tell me why did you wrote the command `polydecomp`, i didn't use it and also don't know how to use it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132560/discussion-between-miracle173-and-learner).